# moment js is picking up the wrong timezone/offset, so the conversion from UTC to local time is incorrect

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I have read several articles, the docs at momentjs and several issues (here on stackoverflow) regarding moment and timezone handling, but I have not found the answer to how moment decides what the local UTC offset is.  I am in the America/Denver timezone and at this time of this writing, the offset is UTC-07:00.  The Windows clock is set correctly and displays the local time properly.  For a UTC timestamp of "2017-04-24 17:33:55", I expect the following code to log displayDate as "04/24 10:12:34"

```
dateString = "2017-04-24 17:12:34"
console.log("dateString: " + dateString)
utc = moment.utc(dateString)
console.log("utc: " + utc.format())
now = moment(utc.format())
console.log("now: " + now.format())
displayDate = now.format("MM/DD HH:mm:ss")
console.log("displayDate: " + displayDate)
```

But, this is what the console shows:

```
dateString: 2017-04-24 17:12:34
utc: 2017-04-24T17:12:34Z
now: 2017-04-24T18:12:34+01:00
displayDate: 04/24 18:12:34
```

I have no idea how it thinks I'm in a timezone with offset of UTC+01:00.  I am not using moment-timezone and have been unable to resolve why moment is picking up the wrong offset.  I noticed there is a TZ environment variable set to America/Denver, so this clearly has no effect.  How does moment determine the local offset?  Is there some sort of default setting that is messed up somewhere?  It must be something on my machine, because the same code works properly on another machine.

In case it helps, this code lives in an AngularJS (version 1.5.8) app.

Cheers,
Rich

Comment: Denver is UTC-6 for that timestamp, not -7.  You should get `2017-04-24T11:12:34-06:00`, which is what I get when I run it in Chrome on Windows with the time zone set as you described.  What browser/version are you running in?  Can you run `tzutil /g` on the command line?  If it doesn't say `Mountain Standard Time` then you're not set for Denver.

Comment: Also, try `new Date().toString()` and `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`  Moment's local time zone is just passed through from the `Date` object.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the comment - you are correct about the offset for Denver - my mistake.  I think it was this way for a couple weeks when DST started.  The date and timezone offset show the following: [js-time: Tue Apr 25 2017 15:06:10 GMT+0100 (Ame), js-tz: -60]
I have no idea where this could be coming from, since the windows clock is set correctly at Mountain Time (US & Canada).

Comment: @MattJohnson is there a way I can give you some credit here?  You helped lead me to the solution, so thanks!

Comment: I think `"Ame"` is the first three chars of `"America/Denver"`, and the rest of the string is being treated as garbage, somehow interpreted as GMT+1.  Just shows that `TZ` environment variable is not reliable on Windows.  No worries on credit, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

From the normal JavaScript Date().toString() output, it gave me a clue about the TZ environment variable as it was set to "America/Denver".  I unset the TZ environment variable, then restarted the web server (Tomcat service) and tried again.  I got the same problem, but decided to reboot the whole machine anyway.  After all, that's the solution to lots of issues on Windows machines...  Sure enough, that worked!

The bottom line is that JavaScript must be using the TZ environment variable (overriding the system date & time settings) and it seems to be only looking at the first three characters.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: *Some* programs will use the `TZ` variable on Windows, such as if they use functions from standard C libraries that take it into account, and also only if the TZ variable is a recognizable POSIX string or time zone ID that matches information the *application* knows about.  Contrast that with Linux and OSX, where the `TZ` environment variable is always considered, because all OS-level time zone functions take `TZ` into account.  So in general, don't rely on the `TZ` variable on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using moment.js then you can convert UTC to local timezone.**

First you will add moment.js library

Then after that define a variable date and assign UTC time zone date time value like

**var date = '2017-12-25 10:50:18';**

//(UTC datetime)

**var stillUtc = moment.utc(date).toDate();**

//Converting in local time zone

**var local = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');**

Get local date time in local variable. You can print local variable and check your answer

**console.log(local);**

**Your console result is '2017-12-25 16:20:18'**

Comment: I found that simplifying to `moment.utc(date).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` also worked

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for getting a similar string to the ISO

```
 const isoDate = `${moment(item.startDate).format()}Z`;
```

Hope it helps.